implied volatility from bond futures american options
I am looking to extract implied normal yield volatility from bond futures american options.
any advice on how to tackle this?
as a separate question, what extra information does an american implied vol give compared to europeans and how does this compare to say implied volatility from swaptions for comparable interest rates?

To extract implied normal yield volatility from bond futures American options, start by selecting an appropriate pricing model that can handle American options, such as the Binomial Tree or Longstaff-Schwartz model. Next, gather relevant market data, including option prices, underlying bond futures prices, and yield curves. With this data, construct a yield volatility surface to illustrate the relationship between strikes and maturities. Then, calibrate your model by using the observed market prices to determine the volatility inputs that align theoretical prices with market prices. Finally, extract the implied normal yield volatility from the calibrated model, which reflects the market's expectations of future yield volatility.
Hope this helps.

I am particularly curious on how to do the last step : "extract the implied normal yield volatility from the calibrated model, which reflects the market's expectations of future yield volatility."

To extract implied normal yield volatility from American options on bond futures, start by selecting a suitable pricing model, such as the Binomial Tree or Longstaff-Schwartz model. Gather relevant market data, including option prices and yield curves, and then calibrate your model by adjusting volatility inputs to align theoretical prices with observed market prices. Finally, extract the implied normal yield volatility by determining the volatility level that matches the model's theoretical option prices to market prices.
